# Which is faster for imputing: R or Python?

Tags: python, r, data-imputation

I have a fairly large dataset (about 40k rows, 40 columns) with many NA's (up to 40% of each variable). All of my work has been done in R so far, but I know R (which I'm told runs only on a single core) won't be able to impute the data with any type of respectable turn around time, especially on my laptop.

While I'm looking into more powerful cloud computing to help, I'm wondering if Python could offer better imputation times (presumably it can be run on more than one core).

I'm also still deciding on the algorithm -- likely Cart, KNN, or Forest. It's survey data.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Python. With sklearn, you have many ways to perform algorithm multicore on your data.
Another reason to use Python: If you want to perform distributed computing you have many modules like DASK which are very easy to use and schedule automatically Tasks on different Machines without spending hours in coding multithreading algorithm.

40k rows, 40 columns are not a big problem for python, BUT I think "R" should be able to handle this, it's a very popular language for statistical algorithms. Maybe some settings are false...

Short:

- Install Python (or better Anaconda)
- on Sklearn-site you will find some [demo code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#random-forests)
- Try it with your Dataset
- Maybe you could benchmark it :)